# Pass along & sign with href to php page help

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this:

```
    browse_cat.php?cat_gr='Mopeds &amp; Traktors'">
```

The browse_cat.php contains this to fetch the above "**category**":

```
    $cat=$_GET['cat_gr'];
    echo $cat;
```

This echo outputs the first word only "**Mopeds**". It wont change if I replace the **&amp**; with **&**.

What is the problem here?

The adress bar when I enter browse_cat.php shows:

```
  browse_cat.php?cat_gr='Mopeds%20&%20Traktors'
```

Thanks

Comment: Can I suggest that you perhaps use a unique ID as your `$_GET` variable instead of faffing around with ugly urlencoded strings? For example, `browse_cat.php?id=3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) and [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/urldecode).
Also, remove the single quotes around your query string.

Answer (score 1):

Your url query values should not have quotes around them. You also need to urlencode the & and the spaces. Here is the correct url:

```
 browse_cat.php?cat_gr=Mopeds%20%26%20Traktors
```

Comment: You could use the php urlencode function to output the correct url, or use the javascript escape function generate the correct url. If the link is always the same, just use an online url encoder.

Comment: In JavaScript it would be `encodeURIComponent`, not the bogus `escape`.

Comment: By the way, if the url is being passed into PHP, you do not need to use urldecode(). PHP will automatically decode the value for you.

Answer (score 0):

%20 is the html entity for a space.
URL shouldn't contain any.